# Refering certain rows in other sheets based on a particular condition

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I require help for making the following table: Consider that I have three sheets in an Excel workbook.

- The first sheet is the summary page. The next two are Subject1 and Subject2.
- Each of these subject sheets has a table with two columns - Bookname and Status.
- 'Bookname' is regarding the name of the book and 'Status' can be Yes or No - indicating whether I have started the book or not.

Therefore, at any given point, in Subject1 and Subject2, there will be several books and each of them will have Y or N assigned to it.

That being the case, I just want to know how I can show only those books - present in Subject1 and Subject2 sheets - which are marked 'Yes' in the summary page. That is, I want in the summary page a table which shows which book i am reading currently.

Comment: You've done a good job explaining this. Can you tell us what you've tried?

Comment: What you're describing seems to be more of a database function than a spreadsheet function. In SQL this would be a fairly simple query that would return your results table. Have you considered Access or SQL Server for your solution?

Comment: @CharlieRB - Well haven't tried much sadly. I know how to refer to values of cells in other sheets. But not sure how I can get the entire row content. E.g.in subject1, a proper row would contain the bookname and the status. (I am also planning to add few other things like colour code, date started, etc.) I dont know how I can get all these values in the summary page.

Comment: @DavidVandenbos - What I am planning to do is for maintaining my own reading list. Therefore thought I can do this in excel. If nothing works, let me try the DB way. But frankly I dont want a DB server running - as I am not going to refer to this list on a daily basis. And moreover, Excel provides other features which make the data look quite intuitive.

Comment: @pnuts - Just to illustrate I have mentioned two sheets. But right now I have some 6 or 7. And moreover, I am planning to create sub-topics which I do not want get hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been mentioned, what you want would be a natural for a database solution. Here is an approach that taps the ability of Excel to connect to external data sources. I have not worked with the approach extensively, so it has to be considered experimental, for me at least, and there may be hidden gotchas that I have not yet uncovered.

The idea is to make a data connection of the workbook to itself, use the Microsoft Query Tool to define a Union query on data tables in the subject sheets of the workbook, and return the query result as a consolidated table in the summary sheet. The data in this table can then be sorted and filtered as required.

Setup of the subject sheets is along the lines you outline (elaborated somewhat). In order for the data in the sheets to be recognized as "tables" by the Query Tool, each book list must be named. For example, the range `A1:E11` in sheet **Subj1** has been named **Subj1** as well, with similar names for the other two data sheets. [1]

[image: Data worksheet Subj1]

To set up the query, start by selecting `From Other Sources` / `From Microsoft Query` from the `Data` tab on the ribbon, choosing *Excel Files* as the data source, and specifying the workbook itself as the source file.

[image: Data source]

The Query Tool will open with the Query Wizard visible. Each of the range names that you defined will be listed as tables, with their column headers as fields. Go ahead and select the fields from the first table, Subj1, to be included in the query. Then click <kbd>Next</kbd> twice to move to the Query Wizard Finish dialog. There, select the `View data or edit query in Microsoft Query` radio button and click <kbd>Finish</kbd>.

[image: Query Wizard]

The Query Tool itself will open up, with a graphical view of the query as specified so far and a listing of the results of the query. Click on the <kbd>SQL</kbd> button on the main menu bar, opening the SQL editor.

[image: SQL editor]

Modify the query so that it will combine all the data ranges (three in my example):

```
  SELECT subj1.subject, subj1.title, subj1.status
  FROM subj1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT subj2.subject, subj2.title, subj2.status
  FROM subj2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT subj3.subject, subj3.title, subj3.status
  FROM subj3
```

After clicking <kbd>OK</kbd>, save the query. You can now embed the query results by selecting `File` / `Return Data to Microsoft Excel`, following the prompts to import the results to the `Summary` worksheet as a sortable and filterable table.

Since Excel thinks the data for the table is from an external data source, you will need to refresh the table after editing the book lists. `Refresh` can be accessed by right-clicking in the table to bring up the context menu. [2]

If you subsequently want to modify the query (for example, to add a category), you can access it via `Data` / `Connections` on the ribbon. Click <kbd>Properties</kbd> in the `Workbook Connections` dialog box and then select the `Definition` tab. Edit the query directly in the `Command text` box; Excel will complain if you press <kbd>Edit query</kbd>.

[image: Result table]

*1. The blue-shaded areas in column E and row 11 are there for future convenience when additional books (or categories) are added. They can be dragged down or to the right to make room for more data while preserving the range name. (Including extra rows in the range name will result in blank rows showing up in the summary table; dynamic defined ranges are not recognized as tables by the Query Tool.)*

*2. Choosing `Table` / `External Data Properties` on the context menu will bring up some useful table formatting properties, including turning off the automatic resizing of the table columns upon a refresh.*

Comment: Thanks a lot! Please give me a day's time to implement and try this out. But I really appreciate the effort that you have taken to explain the procedure in this detail. Thanks again!

Comment: Well executed answer!

Comment: @Chuff - Tried it...worked brilliantly. Thanks again for the detailed explanation. Much obliged.

Comment: Alas this answer is available only for Excel on Windows.